# java.lang.VerifyError while running modified .class file

Tags: java, bytecode

I am working on ASM framework for some time, where i successfully edited a .class file. I am in a situation where I need to replace a method call with another method call. I have achieved this by overriding `super.visitMethodInsn()`

Am posting the coding here:

Unmodified class: `UserSampleClass.java`

```
package checking;

public class UserSampleClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserSampleClass usc= new UserSampleClass();
    usc.display();
}

public String display() {

    System.out.println("Hello Method: "+hello());
    System.out.println("Bye Method: "+bye());
    System.out.println("Hello Method: "+hello());
    return "i'm display";
}

private String bye() {

    return "Bye";
}

private String hello() {

    return "Hello";
}

}
```

The output of the above program will be:

```
Hello Method: Hello
Bye Method: Bye
Hello Method: Hello
```

Now I have modified the original class file and changed the the three method calls (i.e., hello(), bye(), hello()) to other 3 method calls as mentioned below:

to replace first hello method: `replaceFirstHelloInvoke.java`.

```
package chekingDepend;
public class replaceFirstHelloInvoke {


public  replaceFirstHelloInvoke()
{}

public static String replaceFirstHello()    {
    return "one";
}
}
```

to replace the bye method: `replaceByeInvoke.java`

```
package chekingDepend;
public class replaceByeInvoke {

public  replaceByeInvoke()
{}
public static String replaceBye()   {
    return "two";
}

}
```

to replace second hello: `replaceSecondHelloInvoke.java`

```
package chekingDepend;
public class replaceSecondHelloInvoke {

public replaceSecondHelloInvoke()
{}
public static String replaceSecondHello()   {
    return "three";
}
}
```

I have created all these methods as `static` because they can be directly referred through class name.

I am able to successfully generate the modified class through ASM.

Now the problem is that The modified class is not running. When I tried to run it am getting this error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: checking/UserSampleClass, method: display signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;) Incompatible object argument for function call
Could not find the main class: UserSampleClass.  Program will exit.`

I have checked the package dependency also. everything seems to be correct.

I also used the bytecode comparison tool, provided by ASM to check the modifications at byte code level.

All the changes seems to be correct.

I will post the byte codes here:

Unmodified byte code: `UserSampleClass.class`

```
// class version 49.0 (49)
// access flags 0x21
public class checking/UserSampleClass {

  // compiled from: UserSampleClass.java

  // access flags 0x1
  public <init>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 3 L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
    RETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lchecking/UserSampleClass; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x9
  public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 6 L0
    NEW checking/UserSampleClass
    DUP
    INVOKESPECIAL checking/UserSampleClass.<init> ()V
    ASTORE 1
   L1
    LINENUMBER 7 L1
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL checking/UserSampleClass.display ()Ljava/lang/String;
    POP
   L2
    LINENUMBER 8 L2
    RETURN
   L3
    LOCALVARIABLE args [Ljava/lang/String; L0 L3 0
    LOCALVARIABLE usc Lchecking/UserSampleClass; L1 L3 1
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 2

  // access flags 0x1
  public display()Ljava/lang/String;
   L0
    LINENUMBER 12 L0
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    NEW java/lang/StringBuilder
    DUP
    LDC "hello:"
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/StringBuilder.<init> (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL checking/UserSampleClass.hello ()Ljava/lang/String;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    LDC " "
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    LDC "bye:"
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL checking/UserSampleClass.bye ()Ljava/lang/String;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    LDC "    "
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    LDC "hello:"
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL checking/UserSampleClass.hello ()Ljava/lang/String;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 13 L1
    LDC "i'm display"
    ARETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lchecking/UserSampleClass; L0 L2 0
    MAXSTACK = 4
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x2
  private bye()Ljava/lang/String;
   L0
    LINENUMBER 18 L0
    LDC "Bye"
    ARETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lchecking/UserSampleClass; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x2
  private hello()Ljava/lang/String;
   L0
    LINENUMBER 23 L0
    LDC "Hello"
    ARETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lchecking/UserSampleClass; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1
}
```

Modified byte code: `UserSampleClass.class`

```
// class version 49.0 (49)
// access flags 0x21
public class checking/UserSampleClass {

  // compiled from: UserSampleClass.java

  // access flags 0x1
  public <init>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 3 L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
    RETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lchecking/UserSampleClass; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x9
  public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 6 L0
    NEW checking/UserSampleClass
    DUP
    INVOKESPECIAL checking/UserSampleClass.<init> ()V
    ASTORE 1
   L1
    LINENUMBER 7 L1
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL checking/UserSampleClass.display ()Ljava/lang/String;
    POP
   L2
    LINENUMBER 8 L2
    RETURN
   L3
    LOCALVARIABLE args [Ljava/lang/String; L0 L3 0
    LOCALVARIABLE usc Lchecking/UserSampleClass; L1 L3 1
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 2

  // access flags 0x1
  public display()Ljava/lang/String;
   L0
    LINENUMBER 12 L0
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    NEW java/lang/StringBuilder
    DUP
    LDC "hello:"
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/StringBuilder.<init> (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESTATIC chekingDepend/replaceFirstHelloInvoke.replaceFirstHello ()Ljava/lang/String;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    LDC " "
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    LDC "bye:"
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESTATIC chekingDepend/replaceByeInvoke.replaceBye ()Ljava/lang/String;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    LDC "    "
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    LDC "hello:"
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESTATIC chekingDepend/replaceSecondHelloInvoke.replaceSecondHello ()Ljava/lang/String;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 13 L1
    LDC "i'm display"
    ARETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lchecking/UserSampleClass; L0 L2 0
    MAXSTACK = 6
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x2
  private bye()Ljava/lang/String;
   L0
    LINENUMBER 18 L0
    LDC "Bye"
    ARETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lchecking/UserSampleClass; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x2
  private hello()Ljava/lang/String;
   L0
    LINENUMBER 23 L0
    LDC "Hello"
    ARETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lchecking/UserSampleClass; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1
}
```

The overloaded `visitMethodInsn()` method

```
@Override
     public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc) {

         MetaData executionUnitMetaData = new MetaData();

         String[] methodInvocationToReplace =  {"hello", "bye", "hello"};

         String[] replacableClassName = {"chekingDepend.replaceFirstHelloInvoke","chekingDepend.replaceByeInvoke","chekingDepend.replaceSecondHelloInvoke"};

         String[] replacableMethodName = {"replaceFirstHello","replaceBye","replaceSecondHello"};


         if(i<methodInvocationToReplace.length && name.equals(methodInvocationToReplace[i]))    {

            super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, replacableClassName[i].replace('.', '/'), replacableMethodName[i], desc); // replacableMethodDesc[i]);

            i++;

         }else      {

            super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
        }   


      }

    }
```

Here I copy the file from to another directory with same directory structure before executing, so that the original .class file is not modified. the modified .class file is created in a seprate folder with same package structure.

But am clue less why am getting `lava.lang.VerifyError`.

Please help me to sort out this issue.

I use Java 1.6 and ASM 4.0

If the program runs correctly, my output should be:

```
Hello Method: one
Bye Method: two
Hello Method: three
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your original code calls the private instance methods, it does it like this:

```
  ALOAD 0      # push `this`
  INVOKESPECIAL checking/UserSampleClass.hello ()Ljava/lang/String; # call the method.
```

... and the INVOKESPECIAL is going to pop the first operand as the invocation target.

In your modified code, we have this instead:

```
  ALOAD 0      # push `this`
  INVOKESTATIC chekingDepend/replaceFirstHelloInvoke.replaceFirstHello ()Ljava/lang/String;
```

... but the INVOKESTATIC does not pop the opstack element.

The verifier (correctly) figures that this is wrong.

Compare the operand stack requirements for the respective bytecode instructions:

- [INVOKESTATIC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokestatic)
- [INVOKESPECIAL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokespecial)

Comment: Thanks sir. But here display() is a public method. and other 3 are public static methods. but why am getting this error? can u plz explain me.

Comment: I'm talking about the methods that you are calling, not the place you are calling them.  But, OTOH, you don't either show us the code that is doing the "byte code engineering", or describe *clearly* what it is doing.  So I might have misunderstood you.

Comment: I have added the overloaded visitMethodInsn() where the aactual replacement takes place. kindly go through it.

Comment: That confirms what I thought / said in my Answer.  You are replacing a calls to private instance methods with calls to public static methods.

Comment: but we can access the static methods in a non static method with class name ?
so what goes wrong here sir? can u plz explain...!

Comment: can u plz explain how do I pop the operand stack?

Comment: Use the POP instruction.  Or better still, remove the unnecessary ALOAD 0 instructions when you change INVOKESPECIAL (or INVOKEVIRTUAL) to (INVOKESTATIC)

Comment: Thanks a lottt.. It worked. I popped the old instruction by adding super.visitInsn(Opcodes.POP) in the if condition and it worked fine.